# How do I manually trigger Angular Material Date picker filter?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a filter set on a date picker that basically filters out any dates that are unavailable.

This all works as intended, however because it is an Observable getting all the unavailable dates, it doesn't show the filtered dates until an input is given to the date picker first.

Here is my filter:

Get the latest unavailable dates from the service and then filter through those results

```js
    bookingsFilter = (d: Date | null): boolean => {
        this.contentService.bookingResults.subscribe(bookings => this.bookings = bookings);
        const day = (d || new Date()).setHours(14, 0, 0, 0);
        return !this.bookings.includes(day);
    }
```

And a snippet of the template:

```html
   <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="bookingsFilter" ... required />
```

The bookingResults is a behaviour Subject holding an array of dates, whenever a check is done to the back-end, it updates that subject and this filter checks that subject.

All of this functionally works correctly for when a user selects a date and during validation it is checked, the only thing i cant seem to get working is to get it to show the updated filter on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is not possible given the current API. In fact, I'm supposing `this.contentService.bookingResults` is fetching the data from a backend, so it's an asynchronous observable.

`MatDatepicker` has an important behavior: the filter is set to the component every time it opens. With an asynchronous API fetching the data, it's impossible to have the latest data on the filter without any complicated setup.

There are two things you could try, but both of them have their drawbacks.

1. **Show an out-of-date list of forbidden dates:** This is what you're doing right now: showing the forbidden dates grabbed on the last time the datepicker was opened. This is the first approach: grabbing the latest data sometime before you actually open your datepicker. The way it's currently set up (you're complaining that the filter is not working as expected for the first opening) you're grabbing data *during* the datepicker opening. So when you first open it, you grab the list of data, but it doesn't do any effect on the already opened datepicker panel. The dates will be there, without any filtering. The suggestions in other answers here tell you to do a first trip to the backend and grab the forbidden dates in the `OnInit` method. I think this would be an acceptable solution **if your forbidden dates didn't change in a frenetic pace** (in a booking application I think these frequent changes in dates happen and it is critical so this approach is *not* acceptable).
2. **Hold the datepicker opening until you have the data from the server:** This other approach, not suggested in any answer yet, holds the datepicker while you're asking the server for your data. Well... at least this is the experience you'll give to your users. In fact you should close the datepicker as soon as you open it, go grab the data at the server side and reopen the datepicker when the data is finally on the client. IMO this gives the user a terrible UX, but you'd have the latest data in your filter.

   As other answers have already show how to do the approach (1), I'm gonna show this also not that good approach (2) as it guarantees you'll have an up-to-date data on the filter:

```js
// grab a reference to your datepicker
@ViewChild(MatDatepicker) datepicker: MatDatepicker<Date>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.subscribeToOpeningStream();
}

subscribeToOpeningStream() {
  this.datepicker.openedStream
    .pipe(
      tap(() => {
        // close the datepicker
        this.datepicker.close();
        // disable the datepicker so the user didn't try to open it again
        // while going to the server
        this.datepicker.disabled = true;
      }),
      // unsubscribe to the openedStream: it avoids an infinite loop
      // when you repoen the datepicker inside the subscriber function
      take(1),

      // this is when you go to the server to grab the most recent
      // list of forbidden dates. Notice that if you don't go to the
      // server, this would be a potentially synchronous observable
      // and the overall logic on this setup will probably not work
      // without adding a delay(300) to the observables pipe here
      switchMap(() => this.contentService.bookingResults),
    )
    .subscribe((bookings: any) => {
      this.bookings = bookings;
      
      // enable the datepicker again
      this.datepicker.disabled = false;

      // reopens the date picker
      this.datepicker.open();

      // resubscribe to openedStream
      this.subscribeToOpeningStream();

    });
}
```

Here you have a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma613977316433166).

What's still not done with the above solution: improve the UX as much as possible. Maybe a spinner inside the input while opening the datepicker.

Also, consider, if it's on your hands, the possibility of using a websocket so that you could subscribe to changes on the forbidden dates. Used in the right way it could save the UX of your app.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. bookingResults is just a behaviour subject holding an array as this is shared across the app before they get to the filtered date input.

I did however try option 1 but for some reason it did not work, I will look into this more, its probably to do with not waiting for bookings to have a value

Comment: A behavior subject is usually synchronous, so a simple delay before the `switchMap` in approach 2 should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry but is this not the most ridiculous thing?? Why would anyone create a datepicker in such a way that you cannot change the date filter asynchronously?? In my app I need to update the filter whenever the user selects a different month, which works flawlessly if the result is synchronous but as soon as you add an API call it's suddenly impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You could just subscribe in onInit() since you already assign it to this.bookings

Answer (score 0):

you has two problems, the first is the answer of Nabel, you need subscribe and give value to this.bookings in an ngOnInit, remember that your service make an async call, so, in your function "this.bookings" has no value

```
ngOnInit()
{
    this.contentService.bookingResults
        .subscribe(bookings => this.bookings = bookings);
}
```

The second problem is that includes give you always false, you're comparing objects, and the two objects (two Dates) are diferents -yes, has the same value but they are differents., e.g.

```
const date1=new Date()
const date2=new Date()
const equal=date==date1 //equal is false
```

So you can store in bookings the getTime or a string in the way YYYYMMdd, and compare with the d.getTime() or d formated

```
ngOnInit()
{
    this.contentService.bookingResults
        .subscribe(bookings => this.bookings = bookings.map(x=>{
                 return x.getFullYear()
                        +('00'+(x.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)
                        +('00'+x.getDate()).slice(-2)
                 })
        )    
}
```

Now, this.bookings are an array of string, so you can do

```
  bookingsFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
    const date=d.getFullYear()+
               ('00'+(d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+
               ('00'+d.getDate()).slice(-2)
        return this.bookings.includes(date);
    }
```